# Shortcut to open the Gnome Shell user menu

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 20.04

Is there a fast way to open the Gnome Shell user menu (top right) using the keyboard? I would like to easily access sound, wifi, bt, ... options with my keyboard.

I know I can open it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Right</kbd>, <kbd>Right</kbd>, <kbd>Right</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, but that's very slow.

Comment: Does this help? https://linuxconfig.org/add-application-menu-on-ubuntu-20-04-gnome-desktop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To implement a quick shortcut key to open the Gnome Shell user menu, assign following command to a shortcut combination:

```
gdbus call -e -d org.gnome.Shell -o /org/gnome/Shell -m org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu.menu.toggle();'
```

Comment: This doesn't work on Gnome shell v41 and up because it restricts usage of Eval. You may use the workaround provided in the following answer:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1428946/934457