# Shortcuts for keyboard layout Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm using multiple keyboard layout - en, cs, no, zh
I'd like to switch between using different shortcut for each, e.g.

- Ctrl-Shift-1 - English
- Ctrl-Shift-2 - Czech
- Ctrl-Shift-3 - Norwegian
- Ctrl-Shift-4 - Chinese

This way I can switch between the layouts very fast without keeping track what layout I'm actually using as it would be with Opt-Space cycling switch.

With 20.04 I was using the following script, but it seems it is not working in 22.04

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell \                      
 --object-path /org/gnome/Shell \
 --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \
 "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[$1]"
```

Any idea how to achieve the same thing in the latest release?

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to make this work inspired by the other answers. Unfortunately they were lacking some detail so instead will summarize the steps here for assigning keyboard shortcuts to a keyboard layout:

1. Make sure you already have installed all the desired keyboard layouts. They should be shown in the top bar when clicking the language button.
2. Download [GNOME extension Eval-GJs](https://github.com/ramottamado/eval-gjs): This extension is not on 'extensions.gnome.org', the official Gnome Shell Extensions website, so you must download / clone the repo from github.
3. Install the extension as a regular user as described in its README.md:

```
cd eval-gjs-main
make install
```

This will copy it to a folder within your home directory: `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

3. Determine your gnome version by executing:

```
gnome-shell --version
```

4. Edit metadata.json in
   `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/eval-gjs@ramottamado.dev/`

Insert your exact gnome version in the array after the line `"shell-version"`.

Log out, then log in again.

5. Launch Extension manager (gnome-extensions-app)
   Install it if you don't have it, with:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs
```

6. Enable the extension.
   Note: the extension will not show up if your exact gnome version is not in metadata.json as explained above.
7. Create the following bash script `change-layout.sh` and give it execute permissions :

```
#!/bin/bash
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current "$1" 
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell \
--object-path /dev/ramottamado/EvalGjs \
--method dev.ramottamado.EvalGjs.Eval \
"imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[$1].activate()"
```

8. Test the script.
   Run

```
change-layout.sh 0
```

for the first keyboard layout, in the case of OP this is English,

```
change-layout.sh 1
```

for the second layout, etc.

9. Go to `Gnome settings -> Keyboard -> View and Customize shortcuts -> Custom Shortucts`, then assign your desire keyboard shortcut and use one of the commands above for the desired keyboard layout.

Comment: I had to log out and back in to see the extension in the manager.

Comment: @vctls Thanks, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing the `activate()` part of the command:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell \
--object-path /org/gnome/Shell \
--method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \
 "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[$1].activate()"
```

Comment: yes, right, when I ad the activate it prints out the following: ```(false, '')``` but does not change the layout unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

First the problem is that as of GNOME 41, the dbus method Eval() is now restricted with `MetaContext:unsafe-mode` property (see this [commit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/merge_requests/1970/diffs?commit_id=f42df5995e08a89495e2f59a9ed89b5c03369bf8)).

Solution that worked for me:

1. Install [GNOME extension Eval-GJs](https://github.com/ramottamado/eval-gjs) - This extension provides unrestricted Eval() dbus method for running arbitrary code in the compositor.
2. rewrite the layout switching script to use the above extension

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell \
--object-path /dev/ramottamado/EvalGjs \
--method dev.ramottamado.EvalGjs.Eval \
"imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[$1].activate()"
```

Comment: I installed the exension as described, but I get `Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Object does not exist at path “/dev/ramottamado/EvalGjs”`. What can I do next?

Comment: Instead of using a custom `Eval`, why not use the [Quick Lang Switch](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4559/quick-lang-switch/) Gnome-shell extension which simply skips the popup and switches languages instantaneously, **without** affecting any shortcuts, so `setxkbd`, `gnome-tweak-tool`, *Wayland* & X11 all continue to work fine?

Comment: @1mi
`gnome-extensions enable eval-gjs@ramottamado.dev` helped me. Don't forget to relogin after installing the extension and before running the above mentioned command.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that was a solution for me (clean Ubuntu 22.04).
A few notes: update metadata.json file (https://github.com/ramottamado/eval-gjs/pull/1) and install gnome-shell-extension-manager and then enable that extension.

Comment: The extension is in my `.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` folder and metadata.json is as in the mentioned commit. I have Gnome Shell 42.4, however Extension Manager doesn't show it. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

I created GNOME extension to switch among 4 input methods directly.  Since pertinent javascript code is executed without shell command `gdbus`, this doesn't require to use unsafe-mode.

- https://github.com/osamuaoki/inputmethod-shortcuts
- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6066/shortcuts-to-activate-input-methods/

Now, shortcuts are configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Suffer no more! I've made a simple GNOME Shell Extension and I'm sharing it with the world: [Shyriiwook](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6691/shyriiwook/) (also available @ GitHub: [madhead/shyriiwook](https://github.com/madhead/shyriiwook)).

This is a very simple, minimalist extension. It doesn't have any GUI. After installing it, a new D-Bus interface would be exposed in your GNOME Shell session. You could query it for the current configuration or call a method to activate the desired layout:

```shell
$ gdbus introspect \
    --session \
    --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /me/madhead/Shyriiwook \
    --only-properties

node /me/madhead/Shyriiwook {
  interface me.madhead.Shyriiwook {
    properties:
      readonly as availableLayouts = ['us', 'de', 'jp'];
      readonly s currentLayout = 'us';
  };
};

$ gdbus call \
    --session \
    --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /me/madhead/Shyriiwook \
    --method me.madhead.Shyriiwook.activate "de"
```

This is easily scriptable, and you can even put this command raw into a custom shortcut under the "Settings" → "Keyboard" → "Keyboard Shortcuts" → "View and Customise Shortcuts" → "Custom Shortcuts".

What's interesting about it, is that [Shyriiwook](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6691/shyriiwook/) is based on D-Bus, but it doesn't use unsafe and deprecated `Eval` nor any of its alternatives. It re-implements a similar solution using [GJS](https://gjs.guide/) by accessing the same `getInputSourceManager` directly.